# Delete Registry Value

Tags: vb.net, registry, registrykey

I am lookibg for the DLLImport API signature for deleting a registry value.

PInvoke only has the definition for mobile devices.

I am looking for the normal Definition for windows in VB.Net.

I know I can also delete a registry value by using System.Win32.Registry but nevertheless I am looking for the API signature.

Can someone help me out?;)^

Nevermind got it:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking for the DllImport signature of `RegDeleteKeyValue` function.  If so this is it

```
<DllImport("advapi32.dll")> _
Private Shared Function RegDeleteKeyValue( _
  ByVal handle As IntPtr, _
  ByVal keyName As String, _ 
  ByVal valueName As String) 

End Function
```

Comment: Can you show me a sample call if I like to delete a value called puush, like you can see it here: http://puu.sh/7K8A4/d8c00d45cd.png That would be very helpful ^^